# Squashing some commits, but not all, while merging

Tags: git

I have two branches, `master` and `feature`. I want to merge `feature` into `master`, but I have multiple changes in the `feature` branch with messy commits. I don't want to squash these messy commits in the `feature` branch but I want to squash them when I merged the `feature` branch into `master`. One way is using the following command in `master`:

```
git merge --squash feature
```

But the above command will squash all commits and will create a single commit which is not desired. I want to squash some commits, not all of them. For example, I want to squash 3 out of 10, but only while merging into `master`.

What should I do?

Comment: Create a new branch as a "copy" of `feature`, then do this: [How do I squash specific commits on a local branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24310554/how-do-i-squash-specific-commits-on-a-local-branch), then merge the new branch (leaving `feature` alone).

Comment: Take a look at the Squashing Commits part, https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option:

1. `git checkout -b feature_merge feature`.  This effectively makes a temporary copy of the `feature` branch that you can use for squashing while leaving `feature` intact.
2. `git rebase -i $(git merge-base HEAD master)`
3. Squash the commits you want to squash
4. `git checkout master && git merge feature_merge`
5. `git branch -d feature_merge`